# Настройка wi-fi в Windows7

Tags: windows, роутер

Ситуация следующая: имеется ноутбук с Windows7 home, после установки одного из очередных обновлений перестала видится домашняя точка доступа. При этом стабильно находятся все точки доступа соседей. Откат Windows к состоянию до обновления не помог. В качестве роутера используется d-link DIR-300

PS Все остальные устройства находят стабильно находят данную точку доступа.

Подскажите, как можно попытаться решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у меня была такая проблема. Не хотел гаджет цепляться к вай-фаю. Помог сброс вай-фая и перенастройка его.